# Dictionary matching with Different Key Structures

Tags: linq, dictionary, collections, tuples

Using .NET 4.5.1,

```
var largeset = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<DateTime?, long?, long?>, MyClass>();
// 300,000 objects in this
largeset.TryAdd(
    new Tuple<DateTime?, long?, long?>(
        myclassobj.Date, myclassobj.Id1, myclassobj.Id2), myclassobj); 

var inputbits = new Dictionary<Tuple<long?, long?>, MyClass>();
// 10,000 objects in this
inputbits.Add(new Tuple<long?, long?>(newitem.Id1, newitem.Id2), newitem);
```

inputbits has a different structure than largeset, inputbits lacks a Date in its Tuple key.

What is the right way to add items from inputbits to largeset only if largeset does not have the same Id1 and Id2 values?

There will be many matches between largeset and inputbits, I expect about 10% to have no matches, and I need them added to largeset with a null value for Date.

The source of the data is a reporting dump, and it takes a combination of a date plus a parent ID  plus a child ID to uniquely separate rows.

Comment: Are you running this in multiple threads?

Comment: Multiple threads, each with their own instance of inputbits, will read/update largeset.    Thanks.

Comment: Why is `DateTime?` a part of the key in `largeset`?

Comment: There is no atomic method to check a part of the key and add a new item. You'll have to enclose the check and the add in a lock statement.